# SSH agent: `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ECDSA-SK ... from agent: agent refused operation` except very first time

Tags: git, ssh-keys, ssh-agent, yubikey

I have an ecdsa-sk keypair that I generated and added to my github account (tied to a yubikey).  If I try any connection using that key, such as `git push`, I get:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ECDSA-SK "[...]/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk" from agent: agent refused operation
```

No combination of `ssh-add` commands I've tried works (deleting key, re-adding ,etc).  `ssh-add -l` will show the key as present, but I still get the above error.

The only thing that works is to kill the `ssh-agent` and then **immediately** run:

```
ssh-add -K <ecdsa keyfile>
```

If I do that then `git push` will work--*once*.  If I do anything else with the agent first, add other keys, etc. then `git push` will fail (giving the above error) and if I immediately run `git push` a second time it will fail (and continually after until I kill `ssh-agent` again).

I'm unfortunately on Mac (Monterey, M1 chip).  I only have this problem with the esdsa-sk key.  My regular rsa keys work fine.  Am I missing anything or doing something wrong?  I know ecdsa-sk support is relatively new; could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Homebrew's OpenSSH

```
$ brew install openssh
```

Once installed, you have to override the one in your PATH by putting the OpenSSH folder at the beginning of your PATH in your RC file like this

```
$ export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssh)/bin:$PATH
```

Once you've done that and you've sourced your `rc` file you should be able to generate your key

Tested on macOS Monterey and `OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022`